# sklearn.linear_model.LassoLarsIC Early stopping

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What does this mean? It pops out when I am using sklearn.linear_model.LassoLarsIC: "Early stopping the lars path, as the residues are small and the current value of alpha is no longer well controlled"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a comment in `sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py` before the line which spits out the warning:

```
# alpha is increasing. This is because the updates of Cov are
# bringing in too much numerical error that is greater than
# than the remaining correlation with the
# regressors. Time to bail out
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: +1, while that is the reason, what it *means* is that his data - at least in its current form - appears to be ill conditioned.